# Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}(\frac{a}{p})=0$ ( Legendre symbol)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=0$

I'm lost on this one. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How many quadratic residues modulo $p$ are there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just another way of saying that the non-zero residues modulo $p$ split into equally many squares and non-squares.  Depending where you are up to in your study of this subject there are various ways of proving it: here's one.

Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$.  Then each of the $p-1$ non-zero residues can be written in the form $g^k$ for $k=1,\ldots,p-1$, and this is a square if $k$ is even, not a square if $k$ is odd.  Thus there are equally many squares and non-squares.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\;b \neq 0 \pmod p\;$ be a non quadratic residue.

Since $f(x)=bx$ is a bijection from $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$.

Thus

$$\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{ab}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{b}{p}\right)\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)=-\displaystyle\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{a}{p}\right)$$

Comment: The bijection could perhaps be more helpful and clear from $\;\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)^*\to\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)^*$...

Comment: Is there a way to show that for each prime $p$ there exists a $b$ such that b is non quadratic residue? (without using the method of primitive root in the second answer) for $p\equiv 3(4)$ , $-1 \equiv p-1 (p)$ will do, but what in case $p\equiv 1(4) $?

Comment: @dan Yes.. For $p \neq 2$, consider the mapping $$f : (\left(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\right)^*, \cdot)\to(\left(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\right)^*, \cdot) \, ;\,f(x)=x^2$$ Then, since $f(1)=f(-1)$ $f$ is not 1-1 and hence not onto. Any element not achieved by $f$ is a non quadratic residue.

Comment: @dan In fact you can show more using this mapping. Since $f$ is a group homomorphism and $\ker(f)=\{ \pm 1\}$ by the fundamental isomorphism theorem you get that the image of $f$ contains exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ elements. This means that exactly $\frac{p-1}{2}$ elements are non quadratic residues and $\frac{p-1}{2}+1$ are (the $+1$ is for the zero element).